# Sum and group by month using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.6 and postgres 11.

I log changes in quantity of different equipment types which look something like this:

```
{location_id: 1, equipment_type_id: 1, qty: 5, total: 5, date: 'YYYY-MM-DD'},
{location_id: 1, equipment_type_id: 1, qty: 5, total: 10, date: 'YYYY-MM-DD'},
{location_id: 1, equipment_type_id: 2, qty: 5, total: 5, date: 'YYYY-MM-DD'},
{location_id: 1, equipment_type_id: 1, qty: 5, total: 15, date: 'YYYY-MM-DD'} etc
```

I am wanting to be able to get the sum of the total per type grouped by month BUT I only want to get the most recent total for a type and location within the same month. For example if location 1 has 3 entries for type 1, I want to sum the last entry for the month.

Returned data to look something like this:

```
{type: 1, data: [{month: Jan, total: 15}]},
{type: 2, data: [{month: Jan, total: 10},{month: Feb, total: 15}]}
```

I had a quick go but this type of query is well over my head:

```
$singles = EquipmentLog::where('equipment_type_id', '=', 3)
            ->select(
                DB::raw('sum(total) as total'), 
                DB::raw("DATE_TRUNC('month',logged_at) as month")
            )
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->get();

        $totals = [
            ['name' => 'Hives - Single', 'data' => $singles],
        ];
```

Comment: I am a little confused with the question. Do you want to retrieve the last entry for the type and location?

Comment: @SandeepDhakal sorry for the confusion, I want the sum of the total for each type, but only using the last entry for each location in a month. hope that makes more sense?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can get this problem solved in this way. Try it and notify me if something goes wrong.

```
$sub = DB::table('equipment_logs as el')
  ->selectRaw('distinct equipment_type_id, location_id, 
  extract(year from created_at) as year,
  extract(month from created_at) as month, 
  (select total from equipment_logs 
  where location_id = el.location_id
  and equipment_type_id = el.equipment_type_id)
  and extract(year from created_at) = 
  extract(year from el.created_at)
  and extract(month from created_at) = 
  extract(month from el.created_at)
  order by created_at desc limit 1) as total')
  ->where([
    ['equipment_type_id', '=', 3],
    [ /* condition2 */],
    [ /* condition3 */]
   ]);

$data = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
  ->mergeBindings($sub)
  ->selectRaw('equipment_type_id,year,month,sum(total) as total')
  -> groupBy('equipment_type_id’,’year’,’month')
  ->orderByRaw('equipment_type_id,year,month')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am getting groupByRaw does not exist, I think this may not be available with Laravel 5.6?

Comment: Simply modify groupByRaw as groupBy('equipment_type_id’,’year’,’month')

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting this error now too:
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near \"logged_at\"\nLINE 2: extract(year from timestamp logged_at) as year

Comment: Can you tell me what format is your logged_at column?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD - date type

Comment: I swapped it the created_at column which is a timestamp and I get the same error. So I am guessing something else is wrong

Comment: There is a pretty silly mistake please remove timestamp from extract(year from timestamp logged_at) and also use created_at in place of logged_at as the argument needed for extract is timestamp. You can use to_char('2020-01-01','YYYY') and to_char('2020-01-01','MM') if you want to use logged_at.
Please check above query.

Comment: Ok now I am getting:
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near \"from\"\nLINE 11:             order by created_at desc) as total